# im having trouble with this sql triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

i am writing a trigger where it sets new employee salary of 50000 in the salary table when they are hired. So far i started the trigger but don't know how to make the IF statement. Some help with it would be appreciated.

```
EMPLOYEE:
    +-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | staff_id  | int(11)  | NO   |PRI  | NULL    |       | 
    | seniority | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
    | lastname  | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
    | firstname | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

SALARY:
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| staff_id  | int(11)  | NO   |PRI  | NULL    |       | 
| salary    | int(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
delimiter $$

Create Trigger Salary_add
   BEFORE INSERT ON employee
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE num_row INTEGER;
   DECLARE tot_rows INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO tot_rows
   FROM employee
   WHERE staff_id=NEW.staff_id;

SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO num_row
   FROM salary
   WHERE staff_id=NEW.staff_id;

IF num_row > 0 THEN
    UPDATE employee

    WHERE staff_id = NEW.staff_id;

ELSE
INSERT INTO employee
    (staff_id, seniority, lastname, firstname)
    VALUES(NEW.staff_id, NEW.seniority, NEW.lastname, NEW.firstname);
END IF


end$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER salary_add 
AFTER INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO salary VALUES (NEW.staff_id, 50000);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d9b9/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks you peterm so much. All i had to do was to change update to insert.

Comment: Does sqlfiddle by any chance have log, like where in mysql cli you can do /t log